# Grouping by two columns where the value in column A and B are the same

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose that I have this sql table

Table: Chat

```
+---------+----------+----------+
| ToUser  | FromUser | Message  |
+---------+----------+----------+
| 1       |       10 | hi       |
| 8       |        1 | yes      |
| 2       |        8 | blah     |
| 10      |        1 | test     |
| 1       |       10 | anything |
| 9       |        4 | hello    |
| 2       |        3 | hi       |
+---------+----------+----------+
```

How can I group by ToUser and FromUser where it considers the rows where ToUser = 1 and FromUser = 10 are in the same group of the rows ToUser = 10 and FromUser = 1

I tried the following:

```
select ToUser, FromUser
from Chat
group by ToUser, FromUser
```

but this did not help, it considers them different groups.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Sample data is great, but you also need to show us the expected result, i.e. a [mcve].

Comment: what makes those two rows belong to the same group? ... what about row 2 and row 3?

Comment: why do you want to group by? grouping is usuall amde to reduce then number of rows and to get aggregation results, but that group. so i don't think that GROUP BY is the right approach

Comment: @nbk I want to group by to get the latest message happened between user 1 (for example)  and other users

Comment: so you want "anything"? also there is missing some kind of order column as an id or date,else you an't know what is last

Comment: @nbk I want (a,b) and (b,a) be treated as the same pair (same group)

Comment: @Cassini i did understand that, but what you expect as result, and again you are missing an order column

Comment: Ideally you would always store the lower one in A and the higher in B, then you can just do a straight group by

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want (a,b) and (b,a) be treated as the same pair. This is easily done by grouping by the lesser and the greater of the two:

```
select 
  case when touser < fromuser then touser else fromuser end as lesser,
  case when touser > fromuser then touser else fromuser end as greater,
  string_agg(message, ' -> ') within group (order by messagetime) as msg
from chat
group by
  case when touser < fromuser then touser else fromuser end,
  case when touser > fromuser then touser else fromuser end;
```

As of SQL Server 2022 you can use `GREATEST` and `LEAST` instead for readbility.

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c99ccaa9782253baa1a19689dcdcdba4

Comment: Interesting! but in the result  it shows them as different rows, it does not show them as one group

Comment: You say with my query you still see a row for (1, 10) and another for (10, 1)? I don't think this is possible. I've added a demo showing that it is working.

Comment: Sorry I miscopied a row...yes it works fine.